# Performing mathematical operation on the $ y $ coordinates in a list of coordinates

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that contains a set of coordinates in the form `{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, ...}`. I want to edit the list in a manner that takes the `log()` of all the $ y $ coordinates only. Essentially, I want redefine the list such that it now contains `{{x1, log(y1)}, {x2, log(y2)}, ...}`.

Comment: `list[[All,2]]=Log[list[[All,2]]]`?

Comment: `{#1, Log[#2]} & @@@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}`

Comment: `{#[[1]], Log@#[[2]]} & /@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}`

Comment: thanks for the help. cvgmt and wuyudi's answers worked perfectly. Henrik, your suggestion creates something like for every x coordinate, it logs all the other y coordinates. while this wasn't the solution I was looking for, it helped understand how to manipulate lists better so thanks.

Comment: As a reminder, It is customary to upvote the answer(s) that are of value and to accept an answer if it solves the problem. This is how the Stack Exchange sites work. I hope that you will visit the site more often.

Answer (score 2):

One could also use [`MapAt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapAt.html)

```
MapAt[f, {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}, {All, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{x1, f[y1]}, {x2, f[y2]}, {x3, f[y3]}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}} /. {x_, y_} :> {x, Log[y]}
```

Or

```
{#1, Log[#2]} & @@@ {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}}
```

Or the method which provided by @wuyudi

Comment: Careful with the first version; it produces the wrong result if the original list is of length 2!